# How Run Javascript automatically in FlutterWebview

Tags: javascript, webview, flutter

me again ... Is it possible to run javascript automatically in flutter_webview_plugin?.

I Try this by tapping an IconButton

```
flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript('document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");})');
```

it doesn't works.

Actually my goal is to fill two textfields (name and password) and to submit it when the document is loaded.

If I try

```
flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript('document.getElementById("user-id").value = "Phil Osoph"; document.getElementById("pw-id").value = "Baum123"; document._CustomLoginForm.submit(); ');
```

it works but if I try

```
flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript('document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){document.getElementById("user-id").value = "Phil Osoph"; document.getElementById("pw-id").value = "Baum123"; document._CustomLoginForm.submit();})');
```

nothing happens.

Comment: Sounds like `DOMContentLoaded` already happened when the JavaScript is evaluated.

Comment: hmmm ok, but how I can execute javascript without tapping an button? I thought `DOMContentLoaded` do it automatically.

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` is great, but it happens only once and if it already happended when you call `evalJavascript()` the listener will wait forever.

Comment: You write "If I try ... it works". So why not stick with that? There is some risk that the page is not yet loaded though. https://github.com/dart-flitter/flutter_webview_plugin/blob/65025463eece917ccedef8be4234bd476d79f74f/lib/src/base.dart#L58 might help with that. I don't have much experience with WebView plugin though.

Comment: "So why not stick with that?" My goal is to do it automaticly, if I open the Webview it should logged in automaticly and redirect to a sub site. www.example.com/login after login redirect to www.example.com/application. For the automaticly logged in I write value in textfields name and password and Submit it. But yet i musst push a button to write and submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should run the script when the page is loaded

```
flutterWebviewPlugin.onStateChanged.listen((state) async {
  if(state == WebViewState.finishLoad) {
    flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript('document.getElementById("user-id").value = "Phil Osoph"; document.getElementById("pw-id").value = "Baum123"; document._CustomLoginForm.submit(); ');
  }
});
```

Comment: You have forgot closing bracket and semicolon at the end. And I to stupid for it or it doesn't works.

Comment: It works with `state.type == WebViewState.finishLoad`, but just only for the first time, if i close it and start it again this doesn't works.

Comment: You might miss the call to `dispose` after closing

Comment: Where do I have to execute the `dispose` function? I have tried it in Button `onPressed: () {
              
              flutterWebviewPlugin.close();
              dispose();
              //flutterWebviewPlugin.dispose();
            },`

Comment: Could it be possible that the oppening with widget webview is buggy? Because if i oppend it in a (rect) and as hidden webview it works.

Comment: Could it be this issue [link](https://github.com/dart-flitter/flutter_webview_plugin/issues/42) ?

Comment: What is flutterWebviewPlugin? is it an object of WebviewScaffold?

Comment: @Maulik It's a while since I posted this answer and I don't remember. https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/blob/f3d169e778fe4ce107b553f562df4d8d980e68a9/example/lib/main.dart#L15 with https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/blob/f3d169e778fe4ce107b553f562df4d8d980e68a9/example/lib/main.dart#L244 might answer your question.

Comment: hmm ok got it. But I wonder how to call flutterWebviewplugin method only after load webview in flutter app?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using this webview plugin instead of the one provided by the Flutter team? I didn't have a closer look since more than 6 months but I got the impression the one from the Flutter team made much more progress. There might still be some situations where the community plugin is better though. https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter